# How to prevent I/O buffering for piped commands

Tags: bash

The following chain of commands are to

1. ping with datestamp (UNIX),
2. convert the UNIX datestamp to more human-readable format, and
3. output to the terminal and a log file.

`` ping -D localhost 2>&1 | sed 's/^\[\([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\)\]\(.*$\)/echo "[`date -d @\1 +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`] \2"/e' | tee -a ping.log ``

Problem is that as written, the output seems to be buffered in chunks of almost a minute or ~50 lines, unlike the usual second-by-second and line-by-line output from ping.

What is causing the buffering and how can it be avoided?

Comment: Apparently related: [Process each line of output from `ping` immediately in pipeline](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/248916/process-each-line-of-output-from-ping-immediately-in-pipeline). If you have GNU sed you can try adding the `-u` or `--unbuffered` option

Comment: Great! From one of the answers in the link above, adding `-u` flag to `sed` avoids the buffering.

Comment: It's the same question, and the same answer, as at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/467039/ but with `sed` instead of `grep`.  The specific C program being invoked makes little difference.

Answer (score 2):

If it's available in your system, use [unbuffer](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-unbuffer/). Should be as easy as:

```
unbuffer ping -D localhost 2>&1 | unbuffer sed 's/^\[\([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\)\]\(.*$\)/echo "[`date -d @\1 +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`] \2"/e' | tee -a ping.log
```

Comment: `sed -u` looks like a simpler and cleaner solution for now, but do you know when it would be preferable to use `unbuffer`? And which commands would need it?

Comment: `unbuffer` is generic and works with any command. I've used it extensively with various programs including awk, perl and others. It's needed whenever piping is buffered automatically.

Comment: Good to know. When is piping buffered automatically? It confused me that the piped commands, depending on how many and which commands, sometimes get buffered and sometimes don't. I initially thought it was a problem with the code.

Comment: That's a good question, idk myself. I've read around about `stdbuf` which is another program analogous to `unbuffer` that controls stdin/stdout/stderr streams. I guess it's something that either the shell or the kernel controls, but I'd have to do some research on it to know who controls. All I know is that it's external to the program. I had my own scripts with autoflush and everything, and they'd still get buffered, which was really puzzling and how I found unbuffer.